# How to change Skype ringtone on Windows 10 in 2018

Tags: windows-10, skype

Is there a way to change the ringtone in Skype on Windows 10?

Old version of Skype used to have a setting that allowed customizing the ringtone per contact. If I remember correctly, one could also change the default ringtone.

I'm interested in all options, including swapping out audio files.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please obtain your version of Windows from {Settings} | System | About and scroll down to _Windows specifications_. Also, which version of Skype is in use? Open the Skype window, tap Alt, and choose Help then About Skype. Then, once found, click on `edit` above and to the left and add both the Windows Edition and Version number, and the Skype version number to your original post. We must have that to find useful information to help you. Different Skype versions are available at http://www.skaip.org/skype-versions .

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to set different sounds per contact in Skype 8. This functionality, along with others, has been removed.

Source: [How-To Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/369631/microsoft-is-killing-skype-classic-on-november-1-and-heres-why-people-are-upset/)

Answer (score 1):

[https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA339/how-do-i-change-my-skype-settings?q=change+ringtone](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA339/how-do-i-change-my-skype-settings?q=change%20ringtone) offers the keystrokes to open a dialog box in *Skype for Business 2015* in Windows 10 Enterprise, version 1709 AKA Redstone 3 AKA Fall Creators Update AKA Build 16299. When you select **Ringtones and Sounds** from the left side of the dialog box, you see:

[image: Images of dialog box]